# ActiveRecord with remote MySQL in Sinatra

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I'm having trouble finding resources for my specific problem, or at least I don't understand the resources I am finding.

I need my Sinatra app to be able to query a remote MySQL db and return some data. I have read-only access to the db so all I need to do is retrieve it. I know the db works, my connection works, and the query I'm trying to use works. Here is some sample code:

```
db = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'mysql', 
  host:     host, 
  database: database,
  username: user,
  password: pass)
```

Then I'm trying to query the connection with something like this

```
@courses = db.find_by_sql("SELECT *")
```

but the `db` object doesn't have the `find_by_sql` method, or indeed any methods that seem like they'd do the job. Am I missing a step or something to get to where I can query the db or is it something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what the return value of `establish_connection` is. I suspect it is probably not what you want. The normal way to run `find_by_sql` is:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.find_by_sql(...)
```

If you have a model already you can also do:

```
MyModel.find_by_sql(...)
```

Another way is to directly access the connection adapter object and call `execute` on it:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(...)
```

Comment: That actually raises a question I'm not entirely clear on: if I'm accessing a remote database, not building or managing one myself, do I still need to create a data model? I've been imagining this as accessing a file or importing a hash, but is it more than that?

Comment: `ActiveRecord` is an ORM (google it, an ORM maps DB data into objects like `MyModel`, it's not just a hash it's an object mapper). If all you want is to run SQL statements then you don't necessarily need `ActiveRecord` at all. Just run a normal mysql connection using for example this: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/ . But if you want to query data from the remote DB and map them into objects like `MyData` so that you can do `MyData.where(:some_attribute => "something")` then you use `ActiveRecord` and create models as you normally would with Rails also.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the fact that the DB is remote or not. It has nothing to do with the location of the DB. `ActiveRecord` doesn't care where your DB is as long as it can connect to it.

Comment: Does a connection just need to be established, or does whatever is returned need to be passed into ActiveRecord::Base.find_by_sql(...)? Could you possibly provide a brief code sample?

Comment: @thekungfuman The conncetion just needs to be established. `ActiveRecord` stores it for you automatically. http://blog.aizatto.com/2007/05/21/activerecord-without-rails/ . You should learn to use `irb` to test your stuff in the console. You'll progress faster that way. The stuff you are asking unfortunately can't be explained with a brief example. You need to read up on `ActiveRecord` and rails if that's what you're going to use http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html . Maybe you want to just simplify a bit and use the mysql gem directly as I explained above.

Comment: @thekungfuman - See the examples on this page. This will be easier for you to understand and get something working: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/

Comment: Thanks for pointing the way. My only 3rd party service experience so far is using SOAP services where you have to store everything in hashes and reference them with sub-sub-sub keys! I'll look into these docs and gems you recommended. Much appreciated.

Comment: I ended up using the mysql2 gem like you recommended and it's working like a charm. Thanks so much again!